# How do I use DCOUNTA and get the month from a column instead of the entire date in the criteria?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use `DCOUNTA()` to count a range, the problem is that within the range there are date and times and I only want to match the months.

This function doesn't seem to work: `DCOUNTA('QA Productivity Worksheet'!A2:F, "Colleague", {{"Colleague"; $A5}, { MONTH("Date"); MONTH($A$1) }})`

I have also tried: `TEXT("Date", "MM")` with no success.

I'm pretty sure I'm using the wrong syntax to extract just the month from the "Date" column. How would I go about this?

Comment: "Criteria_arr is a range, embedded array or array generated by an array expression that is structured such that the first row contains the field name(s) " -- [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/173497). So it doesn't look like you can apply any scalar functions to the field prior to testing it against the criterion. I suggest using `query` instead, which [allows this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?hl=en#scalar_functions).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use regexreplace first to remove the time part of the time stamp, and then the Text() function will properly transform the way you want.

```
=TEXT(REGEXREPLACE("date timestamp string","\d+:\d+:\d+",""),"MM")
```

Note: the timestamp part of the formula - may need to be altered depending on what exactly your string looks like, if you post an example of the string your starting with - I can modify the regex for you to fit that criteria

ALso if you share an example sheet - we can incorporate your DCOUNTA or a COUNTIF alternative